# Applying functions to members of members... of lists of lists..., etc

Tags: functions, function-construction, functional-style, logic

Suppose that I have a list of depth $k$, and I want to apply a function $f$ to all elements at level $n$ - e.g. $f,\{\{\{a,b\},\{b,c\}\},\{\{c,d\}\}\},3\mapsto\{\{\{f(a),f(b)\},\{f(b),f(c)\}\},\{\{f(c),f(d)\}\}\}$.

Presumably this can be done with some combination of the built-ins `Map`, `Level`, `Apply`, and `Depth`, but I can't seem to get it to work. Is there a way to define a function `Function[<f>,<list>,<levelspec>]` which applies a function only to terms at a certain depth in a list of lists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `{n}` as the level spec to apply the function only to elements at level `n`. If you use `n` as the level spec, the function is applied to elements at levels 1 thru `n`.

```
lst = {{{a, b}, {b, c}}, {{c, d}}}

Map[f, lst, {3}]
```

> {{{f[a], f[b]}, {f[b], f[c]}}, {{f[c], f[d]}}}

#### [`Map >> Details and Options`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html):

[image]